# How to color Google Column Chart's every bar differently and keep them as it is

Tags: javascript, jquery

Though I have successfully colored the bars of google chart individually but not able to keep them when we hover mouse over it. It is getting reset back to blue(which is default).

Here is the jsfiddle of what I have done [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaikratsingh/62cyy27w/3/).

I tried to control the hover behaviour with multiple ways like below.

This I am keeping outside (document.ready) but inside script tag.

1)

```
    $('#chart_div').hover(
      function() {
        $('#chart_client').hide(); // chart_client is another google chart div. 
      }, function() {              // just for testing I was doing hide/show of that.
        $('#chart_client').show();
      }
    );
```

2)

```
    $("#chart_div").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
          $('#chart_client').hide();
        },
        mouseleave:function () {
           $('#chart_client').show();
        }
    },'rect');
```

3)

```
   google.visualization.events.addListener('#chart_div', 'ready', function () {
        $('#chart_div rect').mouseover(function (e) {
            alert('hello');
        });
    });
```

I must be doing something wrong, could you please tell me what and where.

Comment: I have modifed my jsfiddle but there is still some issue. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using below code. Earlier I was trying to create charts using dynamically adding rows into chart(please visit my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaikratsingh/62cyy27w/8/)) but with this below approach I am first preparing data(converting dynamic to static) and adding that static data in to chart's 'arrayToDataTable' method.

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawUserKeywordChart);

  function drawUserKeywordChart() {
        var val = 'Tax:47;Finance:95;Awards:126;Bank:137;Debt:145;';            

        var length = val.length;
        var array = [];

        //preparing data
        while(length>0){
            var sepAt = val.indexOf(";");
            var value = parseInt(val.substring(val.indexOf(":")+1, sepAt));

            array.push(val.substring(0, val.indexOf(":")));
            array.push(value);

            val = val.substring(val.indexOf(";")+1, length);
            length = val.length;
        }

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                  ['Keyword', 'Occurences', { role: 'style' }],
                  [array[0], array[1], '#8AA3B3'],
                  [array[2], array[3], '#A9B089'],    
                  [array[4], array[5], '#848C49'],
                  [array[6], array[7], '#44464A'],
                  [array[8], array[9], '#704610'],
            ]);

       var options = {
                      title: 'Keyword Matches',
                      width: 660, 
                      height: 450,
                      titleTextStyle:{bold:true,fontSize:20},                 
                      legend:{position:'none'}
                    };              

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_keyword1'));                
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Please advice if you find anything wrong here or you have better approach than this.